# What is the purpose of view.bound.origin if it always = (0, 0)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know how to use bound.size but I don't understand bound.origin. In other word, i never use bound.origin if it always equal (0, 0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounds.origin is the point that is displayed at the top left of the view. If you set it to (0, 100), then the point at (0, 100) is displayed at the top left of the view; in other words the view is scrolled up. Most of the time views are not scrolled, but when they are then the bounds.origin changes.

Answer (score 1):

The view's bound represents the view's coordinates in its own coordinate system. It can be useful to modify the bound's origin in some situations.

For example, imagine you have a `UIImageView` with its `contentMode` set to `UIViewContentModeCenter` and the `clipsToBounds` flag set to `YES`, imagine now that you set an image which size is bigger that the `UIImageView`'s size. This produces the effect of a "window" to the image, in which some of the image is clipped outside the `UIImageView`.

Now you can modify what part of the image is shown by modifying the `UIImageView`'s bounds origin without moving the view at all! Because you will be moving the view inside its own coordinate system.

I don't know if this clarifies enough what is the `UIView`'s bounds and how can it be helpful to modify its origin. If you need more explanations, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of bounds vs frame is that bounds always returns 0,0 as the x and y as that is its left-most point. You usually use bounds to get the width and height of a view.

The frame has both the width and height but the origin is in reference to the object's parent view instead of itself.